# Difference between stringByAppendingString and appendString in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring, nsmutablestring

What is the difference between `stringByAppendingString` and `appendString`? If `NSString` is not mutable then how could it append string?

Comment: one return a string object, another not.

Comment: Which one is more efficient if we want to append string? And which one is return string and which one returns another object? Can you please explain?

Comment: i always use `stringByAppendingString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`appendString:` is from [`NSMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString:), `stringByAppendingString:` is from [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:).

The first one mutates the existing `NSMutableString`.

> Adds to the end of the receiver the characters of a given string.

The second one returns a new `NSString` which is a concatenation of the receiver and the parameter.

> Returns a new string made by appending a given string to the receiver.

The reason for that is that the regular `NSString`is immutable and you cannot directly append something to it. The NSMutableString however as the name suggests is mutable and therefore can be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one small question in my head, if we want to append any string, which one we have to use and why?

Comment: if its `NSString` use `stringByAppendingString:` otherwise for `NSMutableString` the other.

Comment: @user3812547 in general the NSString is sufficient unless you have to append many many times. If you have to append a few times it does not really matter - thinking about performance here is really not neccessary unless you need to perform the operation very often

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:) for `stringByAppendingString` states that it

> Returns a new string made by appending a given string to the receiver

so it doesn't modify the existing string - it can't, because as you noted, NSString is immutable

`appendString`, on the other hand, is a mutating method of `NSMutableString` which modifies the receiving `NSMutableString`.